# need to make a non printable background

Tags: html, css

I want to make a java frame or a html page or c# page where i want a picture in a background of exactly a4 size but when i print that page then the picture should no be printed.

Actually that pic is of a form made on paper so it will act like layout of the form on the screen and i will make text boxes and and any other things in their appropriate places and when i print then only the text that i enter should be printed and not the background picture of the form.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS and media directives to remove the background image.

```
body {
    background-image: url('image.gif')
}

@media print {
    body {
        background-image: none;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks man , will give it a try but can you tell me how to make that image size to a4